# When to use javax.ws.rs.core.Application to create RESTful web services?

Tags: web-services, rest, jax-rs

I have developed RESTful web services in two ways:

1. used a class that extends `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` without defining a `web.xml` file, using Glassfish.
2. haven't used `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` but included a `web.xml` and a Jersey implementation, using Tomcat.

Is there a preferred way of building RESTful web services with JAX-RS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` class is the preferred way and also the only portable way of configuring resources and providers in a JAX-RS web service,
so if possible that would be the recommended way to set it up.

But that works well only in JAX-RS aware servlet containers or application servers, for JAX-RS non aware servers you need other ways for deployment and that most of the times means some proprietary servlet class of the JAX-RS implementation you are using.

To get more details on the subject, see for example the Jersey documentation, [Deploying a RESTful Web Service](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/jax-rs.html#d4e188) (for Jersey v1.x) and [Application Deployment and Runtime Environments](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html) (for Jersey v2.x).

Comment: The guide states that it is possible to reuse ResourceConfig - Jersey's own implementations of Application class.  Compared to Application, the ResourceConfig provides advanced capabilities to simplify registration of JAX-RS components.