# Error Handling - Jersey

Tags: java, rest, error-handling, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am trying to use the `ExceptionMapper` in Jersey, but it looks like that `toResponse()` method is not been called. Do I need to include dependencies?

```
@Provider 
public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

    @Override 
    public Response toResponse(Throwable ex) {
       //build responde
    } 
}

public class BulkLoadAPI {  
    @POST   
    @Path("throwException")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)     
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response throwException() throws Exception {         
        throw new Exception("ERROR");  
    }
```

**EDITED**

I solved using the code above:

```
package service;

    import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
    import service.errorhandling.GenericExceptionMapper;

    public class MyConfiguration extends ResourceConfig{
        public MyConfiguration(){
            GenericExceptionMapper myExceptionMapper = new GenericExceptionMapper();
            register(myExceptionMapper);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The ExceptionMapper is probably not being registered. It works fine for me (given `@Path` is included on `BulkLoadAPI` class). Can you show your application configuration.

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet. I already solved the issue. I think it is a know bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25418684/when-to-use-javax-ws-rs-core-application-to-create-restful-web-services

Comment: This is not a bug. This is the way how you register providers (and resources) in a Jersey app. See [Registering Resources and Providers in Jersey 2](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2013/11/19/registering-resources-and-providers-in-jersey-2/) to get more info.